# Nested List-comprehension returning list of lists rather than a single list

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested, list-comprehension

I have a double for-loop which works perfectly fine.
Given a list of categories, it fills out the "blanks" and returns a list with 1000+ URLs.

However, when converting the loop into a nested list-comprehension, it returns a list of lists.

I am aware of the possibility of flattening it, however I would like to know whether I am doing something incorrectly in the first place.
I would rather prefer avoiding the extra steps of flattening it.

Above-mentioned for-loop:

```
for cat in categories:
    page_count = get_page_count(cat)
    for page in range(1,page_count+1):
        urls_to_scrape.append("xyz.com/" + cat + f"all?page={page}" )
```

The list-comprehension I attempted:

```
urls_to_scrape_comp = [["xyz.com/" + cat + f"all?page={page}" for page in range(1,get_page_count(cat))] for cat in categories]
```

As mentioned initially, the ideal outcome would be a single list using a list-comprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the extra brackets and reverse the order of the comprehensions

```
urls_to_scrape_comp = ["xyz.com/" + cat + f"all?page={page}" for cat in categories for page in range(1,get_page_count(cat))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap the inner for between brackets and you should be fine:

```py
urls_to_scrape_comp = ["xyz.com/" + cat + f"all?page={page}" for page in range(1,get_page_count(cat)) for cat in categories]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this yields wrong results.
I get more results than expected.
@Simon's answer works perfectly.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to reverse the order... @Simon got it right :)